# How can I move MYSQL query to Laravel Eloquent subquery?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

My query like this:

```
SELECT AVG(c.total) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total, b.`app_id` FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT `app_id`, `insurance_id`
         FROM `application`
         WHERE `price` IS NOT NULL AND `created_at` >= "2015-11-01 00:00:00"
         GROUP BY `app_id`, `insurance_id`
    ) as b
    GROUP BY b.`app_id`
) as c
```

How can I implement this query to Laravel Eloquent?

My table data is like this;

```
+------+--------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| id   | app_id | insurance_id | price         | created_at          |
+------+--------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
| 3867 |  33846 |           10 | NULL          | 2015-11-20 17:50:26 |
| 3866 |  33846 |            4 | 642,42        | 2015-11-20 17:50:17 |
| 3865 |  33846 |            7 | 687.68        | 2015-11-20 17:50:02 |
| 3864 |  33846 |            8 | NULL          | 2015-11-20 17:49:56 |
| 3863 |  33846 |            3 | 540.7500      | 2015-11-20 17:49:55 |
| 3862 |  33846 |            1 | 988.240000000 | 2015-11-20 17:49:54 |
| 3861 |  33846 |            2 | NULL          | 2015-11-20 17:49:45 |
| 3860 |  33845 |           10 | 565.80        | 2015-11-20 17:22:25 |
| 3859 |  33845 |            4 | 504,90        | 2015-11-20 17:22:15 |
| 3858 |  33845 |            5 | 459.65        | 2015-11-20 17:22:04 |
| 3856 |  33845 |            7 | 664.58        | 2015-11-20 17:21:56 |
| 3857 |  33845 |           10 | 565.80        | 2015-11-20 17:21:56 |
| 3855 |  33845 |            8 | NULL          | 2015-11-20 17:21:54 |
| 3854 |  33845 |            1 | 987.420000000 | 2015-11-20 17:21:48 |
| 3853 |  33845 |            3 | 518.6900      | 2015-11-20 17:21:47 |
| 3852 |  33845 |            2 | NULL          | 2015-11-20 17:21:44 |
| 3851 |  33845 |            4 | NULL          | 2015-11-20 17:21:31 |
| 3850 |  33845 |            7 | NULL          | 2015-11-20 17:21:30 |
| 3849 |  33845 |            5 | 459.65        | 2015-11-20 17:21:26 |
| 3848 |  33845 |            3 | 518.6900      | 2015-11-20 17:21:23 |
+------+--------+--------------+---------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are your models like? You certainly can get the same results that you get from this query using Eloquent, depending on how you go about it you may end up using two queries, a view, using raw SQL, or cleverness.

Comment: Thank you @JoshRumbut Actually I'm figure out with raw SQL. I can use a view but I'll use that query once for a week for calculation for avg count insurance company who has return price.
I edited my query first query for distinct result second is for counting and thirth one for average.
I just wonder how can I do this complex query with eloquent? Is there any solution?

Comment: You could start by re-factoring each individual SQL component into its Eloquent equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution will be to use the `DB` interface for this.

You could run the query like this:

```
$averages = \DB::select('SELECT AVG(c.total) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total, b.`app_id` FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT `app_id`, `insurance_id`
           FROM `application`
           WHERE `price` IS NOT NULL AND `created_at` >= "2015-11-01 00:00:00"
           GROUP BY `app_id`, `insurance_id`
        ) as b
        GROUP BY b.`app_id`
    ) as c');
```

You can take a look at what `$averages` looks like and what it contains and what methods are available for it using `php artisan tinker` which is a very useful tool for experimenting to find the solutions to problems.

If you want to set the `created_at` clause dynamically you can do something like this:

```
$dateString = '2015-10-15 00:00:00';
$averages = \DB::select('SELECT AVG(c.total) FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as total, b.`app_id` FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT `app_id`, `insurance_id`
           FROM `application`
           WHERE `price` IS NOT NULL AND `created_at` >= "?"
           GROUP BY `app_id`, `insurance_id`
        ) as b
        GROUP BY b.`app_id`
    ) as c', [$dateString]);
```

If you need the results of a query like this turned into a `Model`, look into [Model#hyrdrate](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrate), you can even skip using `DB` and go straight to a model with [Model#hydrateRaw](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrateRaw), but since this query returns only one column that may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I though maybe someway I can use like subselect function for `FROM` part too. Anyway as far as this is the best solution I found. Thank you.